# Get image metadata from image within S3 bucket using lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

So I am trying to strip the metadata of images within an S3 bucket using triggers.

I have got it working so when things are uploaded to the S3 bucket, the lambda function runs, however I get an error saying this when I run my code:

`ValueError: embedded null byte`

If I have the image file locally and run it without using the boto3 stuff, I am returned with JSON which is my formatted metadata, So my issue is just getting the data returned to me from the S3 bucket in a format that can be read.

Really stuck and a bit confused as to what is actually happening, as I cannot seem to print out the body of the response to get a better idea.

Any help on how to solve this would be much appreciated :)

```
import exifread
import json
import boto3


#### INFO ####
# Latitude - North
# Longitude - West


def formatLocation(value):
    value[2] = value[2].num / value[2].den
    return {"degrees": str(value[0]), "minutes": str(value[1]), "seconds": str(value[2])}

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Set data values
    data = {"time": "", "date": "", "location": {"lat": {"degrees": "", "minutes": "", "seconds": ""}, "long": {"degrees": "", "minutes": "", "seconds": ""}}}

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket="***BUCKET_NAME", Key="IMAGE_NAME.HEIC")
    print(response['Body'])
    
    # Open image file for reading (must be in binary mode)
    f = open(response['Body'].read(), 'rb')
    tags = exifread.process_file(f)

    datetime = tags["EXIF DateTimeOriginal"].values.split(" ")

    # Set data
    data["date"] = datetime[0]
    data["time"] = datetime[1]
    data["location"]["lat"] = formatLocation(tags["GPS GPSLatitude"].values)
    data["location"]["long"] = formatLocation(tags["GPS GPSLongitude"].values)


    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(data)
    }
```

Comment: Which line of code is throwing that error? Can you provide the full error message?

Comment: @MarkB, the error is being thrown on `f = open(response['Body'].read(), 'rb')`, the error is `ERROR] ValueError: embedded null byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 24, in lambda_handler
    f = open(response[u'Body'].read(), 'rb')`

Comment: Read the documentation for [get_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object), specifically what it returns.

Answer (score 3):

`get_object` returns a [StreamingBody](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html) object in the response, not an object that you can call open on.  For many use cases, you can simply pass the result of `response['Body']` to a consumer.  However, if that consumer expects a file object, you might need to wrap it with BytesIO, since StreamingBody doesn't support seeking:

```python
import io
    # ...
    response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket="***BUCKET_NAME", Key="IMAGE_NAME.HEIC")
   
    tags = exifread.process_file(io.BytesIO(response['Body'].read()))
```